# Sample code to successfully create a Multisend transaction

Tags: gnosis-safe

Every time I create a multi-send transaction and send it to the safe transaction api, I get the following console errors. The transaction still gets sent to the safe transaction api though.

```
"Metamask - RPC Error: execution reverted {code: -3200, message: 'execution reverted'}"
"Metamask - RPC Error: execution reverted: MultiSend should only be called via delegatecall"
```

My multisend transaction code is as follows:

```
const transactionsToExecute = [{to: 0x..., data: 0x..., value: 10000}, {to: 0x..., data: 0-x..., value: 20000}]

const options = {
   nonce: currentNonce,
}
```

Do I need to be concerned about this error and is this the proper way to create a multi send with the **CORRECT** gas estimation. The reason I ask is because previously I would set:

```
const options = {
   nonce: currentNonce,
   safeTxGas: 0
}
```

Setting the safeTxGas to 0 got rid of the console.errors from Metamask, but it would sometimes give an incorrect gas estimate. When I go onto Gnosis to execute, I would get the "this transaction may fail" error and would have to manually increase the gas limit.

Code to send it to the service

```
 const safeTxHash = await safeSdk?.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);

    await safeSdk?.signTransaction(safeTransaction);

    await safeService.proposeTransaction({
      safeAddress: safeAddress,
      safeTransaction,
      safeTxHash,
      senderAddress: account,
    });
```

Any guidance or sample code to ensure I'm doing this the right way would be great!

Comment: Could you also add a code how you actually create the Safe transaction and send it to the service?

Comment: Added it to the post

Comment: Bumping this as I have not had an answer